# Reuse the same winform in procedure

Tags: vb.net

I apologize if my question title is a bit vague. I have the procedure below that calls the form. The hyperlink calls the same form, passing through a sub. All that works well, the problem is that if I click one link and then another, the form opens twice, which is what is supposed to happen because I am instantiating the form as New.

What I want to do is to only have same form open so that if the user clicks links then only one form opens not several.

```
    Private Sub dsbPositionBoard_FollowHyperlink(Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink) Handles Me.FollowHyperlink

    'This procedure runs when any of the hyperlinked cells in the position dashboard are clicked
    'The hyperlinks open the frmDefinition on the assigned defintion. The procedure calls
    'the function. 

    'The hyperlinked cells are assigned under the ThisWorkbook/Open event.

    Dim definitionForm As New frmDefinitions

    Select Case Target.TextToDisplay

        Case "Exempt"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.exemptDefinition()

        Case "Employee Pay Distribution for Ranges", "Low Third", "Upper Third"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.lowerThirdDefinition()

        Case "Market Percentiles"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.marketPercentileDefinition()

        Case "Min", "Mid", "Max", "Salary Range to Mkt"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.payGradeWidthDefintion()

        Case "Total Cash Compensation Data"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.totalCashCompDefition()

        Case "Compa-Ratio"
            definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
            sheetView.compaRatioDefinition()

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, come on! I didn't realise about that until now! I did give the right answer to a previous question of yours and you haven't said a word about it still. I understand that you have used it because it had precisely to do with Excel (a basic error not allowing you to do anything)! Are you planning to do the same now? Because will be the last time I will help you. Ungrateful people is something which I don't like at all.

Comment: @varocarbas, you are absolutely right and my apologies. I forgot to mark your response as the answer and I did use your resolution on the last question you answered.

Comment: OK, if everything was a misunderstanding then no problem. I tend to say things pretty directly, I hope that you haven't found my tone inadequate.

Comment: @varocarbas, not at all. Please and thank yous gets us a long way.  did neither, so excuses on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: either defining the given `frmDefinitions` variable globally and closing/opening it when required; or passing it as an argument to the function.

I guess that the best option for your situation (by assuming typical conditions) is the global definition. Below I am including a small code based on a standard `Form`, which you shouldn't find any problem to adapt to your specific `frmDefinitions` class:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim definitionForm As New Form

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        definitionForm.Close()

        definitionForm = New Form
        definitionForm.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, when you click on `Button1`, the Form `definitionForm` is used over and over (previous instance closed and new instance created and opened).